# Click a input type submit - Mechanize Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, mechanize, mechanize-ruby

I am trying to click a button which is actually a submit without a form which looks some thing like this and store the result in an object

```
<div class="searchBar-input">
    <input id="front-page-search" value="Enter Keyword(s)" type="text">
</div>


<div class="searchBar-submit">
    <input id="searchBtn" value="Search" type="submit">
</div>
```

I have tried puts page.forms and I am getting nothing as there is no form on the page. Its just a text box whose value I have to submit.

I have googled but I found everything about form submit and links. How can I click this? Any suggestions.Thanks in advance

Comment: Clicking that button in your browser might do something but that won't mean anything to mechanize. No form means nothing to submit.

Comment: @pguardiario that is not a form but on clicking submit it should post a value that is present in the input box. And I am sure there is no form.

Comment: Right. I'm saying that without a form that's not going to happen.

Comment: Sure, you can post the data to an url the normal way which is with `Mechanize#post`

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<div class="searchBar-submit">
   <input id="searchBtn" value="Search" type="submit"  onclick="document.forms[0].submit();" ></div>
```

Comment: I am using mechanize and I am trying to crawl other site so onclick is  not under my control